# How do I find disk name with statvfs?

Tags: linux, filesystems, posix, system-calls

I'm using [statvfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/statvfs.2.html) to collect information on a specific file. I would like to obtain the disk name/partition as well (like `/dev/sdb1`, `/dev/media` and so on). However the `statvfs` struct doesn't seem to provide such data. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getmntent()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getmntent.3.html):

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    #include <mntent.h>
>
>    FILE *setmntent(const char *filename, const char *type);
>
>    struct mntent *getmntent(FILE *stream);
>
>    int addmntent(FILE *stream, const struct mntent *mnt);
>
>    int endmntent(FILE *streamp);
>
>    char *hasmntopt(const struct mntent *mnt, const char *opt);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> ...
>
> The mntent structure is defined in  as follows:
>
> ```
> struct mntent {
>     char *mnt_fsname;   /* name of mounted filesystem */
>     char *mnt_dir;      /* filesystem path prefix */
>     char *mnt_type;     /* mount type (see mntent.h) */
>     char *mnt_opts;     /* mount options (see mntent.h) */
>     int   mnt_freq;     /* dump frequency in days */
>     int   mnt_passno;   /* pass number on parallel fsck */
> };
> ```

For example:

```
FILE *fp = setmntent( "/etc/mtab", "r" );
for ( ;; )
{
    struct mntent *me = getmntent( fp );
    if ( NULL == me )
    {
        break;
    }

    ...
}

endmntent( fp );
```

Given a file name, you'll have to do some coding to match the filename to the file system mount point.  The easiest way is probably to match the `f_fsid` field from the `struct statvfs` from the file to the `f_fsid` of a mounted filesystem obtained by calling `statvfs()` on the file system's mount point from the `struct mntent` returned by `getmntent()`.